# Обойти ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, парсер

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://pmkedu.pro/schedules/fulltime/11SSA/2020-10-10')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

element = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-text')
elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element), 'html.parser')
title = elem_soup.find_all('div')[1].text

element = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-text')
elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element), 'html.parser')
title1 = elem_soup.find_all('div')[6].text

element = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-text')
elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element), 'html.parser')
title2 = elem_soup.find_all('div')[11].text

print('Расписание:')

if '' in title:
    print(title)
if '' in title1:
    print(title1)
if '' in title2:
    print(title2)
```

Данный код предназначен для парсинга HTML сайта колледжа, для того, чтоб выводить кол-во пар и их название.

Если в расписании 3 пары - все хорошо выводится, если 2 пары - то начинается ошибка в 17 строке, т.к. отсутсвует пара.

Как сделать так, чтобы если выводится пустота, то пропускать без ошибки?

Comment: Может, в начале добавить проверку на длину массива (количество  elem_soup.find_all('div')), как я понимаю, в нём же проблема?

Comment: @Анастасия, возможно и так, сейчас попробую сделать.

Comment: Попытался через len сделать проверку, все такая же ошибка.

Comment: зачем три раза find_all одного и того же???

Comment: @Jack_oS, каждое find_all со значением строки - строка с парой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://pmkedu.pro/schedules/fulltime/11SSA/2020-10-10')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
# один раз находим карточки
cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-body')
for card in cards:
    # в карточка - один заголовок и время
    title = card.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
    time_start = card.find('div', class_='text-right').text.strip()
    print(title, time_start)
    # и один блок card-text
    card_text = card.find('div', class_='card-text')
    lessons = card_text.find_all('div', class_='lead')
    # с несколькими предметами
    for each in lessons:
        print(each.text.strip())
```

выведет:

```
ССА-20-1/3 Начало: 8.30
1 Информатика
2 Иностранный язык
```

и не будет "спотыкаться" при изменении количества, при
url = 'https://pmkedu.pro/schedules/fulltime/pospelova_ia/2020-10-15' выведет:

```
КС-20-1/3 Начало: 8.30
1 История
2 Науч.картина мира: Химия
3 Математика
ССА-20-1/3 Начало: 9.40
2 Иностранный язык
3 Науч.картина мира: Химия
4 История
ТКПД-20-1 Начало: 8.30
1 Науч.картина мира: Химия
2 Информатика
3 Русский язык
```

Comment: Воу, Вы уменьшили мой код, за что я Вам благодарен. Даже добавили время начала пары, кхе.